# Javascript function with multiple agruments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an function that takes an array as an input.
How can I modify it to work with variable arguments as well as arrays.
For example I want `arrSum(1,2,3) === arrSum([1,2,3])` to return `true` i.e. both should return 6

```js
const arrSum = arr => arr.reduce((a,b) => a+b,0)
console.log(arrSum([1,2,3]))
```

Comment: Use the `arguments` variable.

Comment: FWIW, I would advice against designing the API to be *that* flexible. Accepting a variable number of arguments, fine. Accepting an array, fine. Accepting *either*? No. I'd go with the variadic function, and if you ever have an array of values it's easy enough to apply that using the spread operator or `arrSum.apply(null, arr)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `spread syntax` with `concat`. In first case you will get array with another array inside and in second case just an array of arguments but with `[].concat(...arr)` you will transform that to array of arguments for both cases.

```js
const arrSum = (...arr) => [].concat(...arr).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
console.log(arrSum([1, 2, 3]))
console.log(arrSum(1, 2, 3))
console.log(arrSum([1, 2, 3], [4], 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problems in many way , one way if you're using arrow function would be like this using rest operator

```js
const arrSum = (...arr) => {
    // if we have just on param which is array
    if (arr.length === 1) {
        return arr[0].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    }
    return arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
};
console.log(arrSum(1, 2, 3)); // 6
console.log(arrSum([1, 2, 3])); // 6
```

in the code above we use rest operator learn more [rest_parameters MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

also we can use normal functions using the variable **arguments** inside functions like this

```js
function arrSum(args) {
 
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        return arguments[0].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    } else {
        return [].reduce.call(arguments, (a, b) => a + b, 0);
    }
}
console.log(arrSum(1, 2, 3));
console.log(arrSum([1, 2, 3]));
```

learn more about
[arguments Object MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-)

US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

so the same problem can be solved many ways choose what works best for you .

Answer (score 0):

A solution example:

```js
function arrSum( nums ) {
  var n = 0;
  if ( typeof( nums ) != 'object' )
    return arrSum( arguments );
  for ( var i = 0; i < nums.length ; i++ )
    n += nums[ i ];
  return n;
}

arrSum( 1, 2, 3 );
arrSum( [ 1, 2, 3 ] );
```