# Function with multiple arguments in python

Tags: python

I have an function that takes an array as an input. How can I modify it to work with variable arguments as well as arrays. For example I want `arrSum(1,2,3) == arrSum([1,2,3])` to return `True` i.e. both should return 6

I have already asked [this same question for JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47942018/8979804) but when I tried to implement the same technique in Python I am getting totally unexpected errors.

This is what I have tried to do based on my current knowledge of python.

```
def arrSum(*args):
    listOfArgs = []
    listOfArgs.extend([*list(args)])
    return sum(listOfArgs)
```

It works perfectly for `arrSum(1,2,3)` but returns error for `arrSum([1,2,3])`
`arrSum(1,2,3)` returns `6` which is the expected output.
But `arrSum([1,2,3]) returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 7, in <module>
  File "python", line 4, in arrSum
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Doing a `print(listOfArgs)` before `return sum(listOfArgs)` prints `[[1,2,3]]`.

[REPL.it](https://repl.it/@kriadmin12/StunningDelayedKillifish) link of the function

Comment: "getting totally unexpected results" -- please include input, expected output and actual output in your question

Comment: @khelwood I added a link to repl for that but I shall update the question too :)

Comment: What would the expected output of `arrSum(1)` be? `1` or an error because the single argument isn't iterable?

Comment: Have you tried to add a `print(listOfArgs)` in your function yet? Just before the `sum()`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes I tried that and it returns `[[1, 2, 3]]`

Comment: @RohitKumar: so you have a bug in your code there, you made an incorrect assumption somewhere. Note that Python is not Javascript, you can't apply the same principles. Note that the JS code uses `.concat(...arr)`, not `.concat(arr)`, for example!

Comment: You need to check if your argument is a list of not, and act accordingly. A simple loop with `isinstance` will do.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know it it `.concat(...arr)` and that is the reason I did `listOfArgs.extend([*list(args)])`

Answer (score 2):

The Javascript spread operator treats an array of values and a array containing another array of values **exactly the same**:

```js
[].concat(...[1, 2])
Array [ 1, 2 ]
[].concat(...[[1, 2]])
Array [ 1, 2 ]
```

It essentially flattens multiple arrays:

```
[].concat(...[[1, 2], [3, 4]])
Array [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

but only by one layer:

[].concat(...[[[1, 2]]])
[[ 1, 2 ]]
```

Python is much more exact. There is no implicit flattening, you have to do it *explicitly*:

```
def arrSum(*args):
    if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], list):
        args = args[0]
    return sum(args)
```

If you wanted to replicate the support for multiple lists (so `arrSum([1, 2], [3, 4])`, I'd just reuse the [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists) top answer:

```
import collections

def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, (str, bytes)):
            yield from flatten(el)
        else:
            yield el

def arrSum(*args):
    return sum(flatten(args))
```

Comment: It fails for `arrSum(1,2,3,[1,2,3])` :(

Comment: @RohitKumar: you didn't include that in your question. I already addressed that in my edit however.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you have a list, or an int. :)

Here, this function assumes you will only receive integers and list of integers.

```
def arrSum(*args):
    ret = 0
    total = 0
    for elem in args:
        #   If you have a list, adds the sum of the list, else, simply add the int.
        if isinstance(elem, list):
            total += len(elem)
            ret += sum(elem)
        else
            total += 1
            ret += elem

    average = ret / total
    return ret, average

print arrSum([1, 2, 3])
print arrSum(1, 2, 3)
# both outputs : 6
```

Comment: This works for only doing sum. But how will I implement a average with it. I mean what if I do `average(1,2,3,[1,2,3])`. I think I might have to write a helper function for that

Comment: Well, you ask for a function that would sum all the numbers, not make the average. But this would also be simple to do. :)

Comment: I don't think it will simple to calculate the number of arguments

Comment: See my updated answer to see how easy it was to get the average.

Comment: It completly fails for `arrSum([1,2,3],4,5,6)`. But martijin's answer solves that problem. Thanks

Comment: It does not for me, since it returns an `int`, and prints `3` for the average of (1+2+3+4+5+6) = 21, divided by 6, it makes 3. If you make the division using **float**, you will correctly have 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

After taking inspiration from Martijin's answer I came up with a solution of my own(and even came up with a spread function for python):-

```
def spread(arg):

 ret = []

 for i in arg:

   if isinstance(i,list):

     ret.extend(i)

   else:

     ret.append(i)

 return ret

def arrSum(*args):
    a = list(args)
    m = []
    m.extend(spread(a))
    return sum(m)
print(arrSum([1, 2, 3]))
print(arrSum(1, 2, 3))
print(arrSum([1, 2, 3], [4], 5))
```

[Working REPL.it link](https://repl.it/@kriadmin12/StunningDelayedKillifish)

Comment: There is no point in extending an empty list. You don't need to convert `args` to a list either, as all you do is iterate over the sequence. So you can just use `return sum(spread(args))`.

Comment: Your `spread()` function is otherwise a more limited version of the `flatten()` function I referenced in my answer (limited to a single level of values and lists).